# python - How select.select() works?

Tags: python, select

### Background:

I'm familiar with C's `select()` function. I've been using this function for many purposes. Most of them, if not all, for reading and writing to pipes, files, etc. I must say that I've never used the error list, but this is not involved in the key question.

### Question:

Does Python's `select()` behave as follows?

It turns out to me that `select()` on Python behaves a different way despite the [*straightforward*](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#module-select) interface to C `select()`. It seems that `select()` returns the very first time a file is ready for reading. If you read the file while leaving some bytes to be read, calling `select()` will block. But, if you call `select()` again after a previous call to `select()` was returned without any read call between these two calls, `select()` will return as expected. For example:

```
import select
# Open the file (yes, playing around with joysticks)
file = open('/dev/input/js0', 'r') 
# Hold on the select() function waiting
select.select([file], [], [])
# Say 16 bytes are sent to the file, select() will return.
([<open file '/dev/input/js0', mode 'r' at 0x7ff2949c96f0>], [], [])
# Call select() again, and select() will indeed return.
select.select([file], [], [])
([<open file '/dev/input/js0', mode 'r' at 0x7ff2949c96f0>], [], [])
# read 8 bytes. There are 8 bytes left for sure. Calling again file.read(8) will empty the queue and would be pointless for this example
file.read(8)
'<\t\x06\x01\x00\x00\x81\x01'
# call select() again, and select() will block
select.select([file], [], [])
# Should it block? there are 8 bytes on the file to be read.
```

If this is the behaviour of `select()` in Python, I'm okay with that, I could handle it. Not what I expected, though, but it's fine. I know what I can do with it.

But if this is not the behaviour of `select()` I would appreciate someone to tell me what I'm doing wrong. What I read about `select()` is what the Python docs say: "select() returns if any file in the read|write|error list is ready for read|write|error.". That's OK no lies there. Maybe the questions should be:

- When a file is considered to be ready for reading in python?
- Does it means a file that has never been read?
- Does it means a file with bytes to be read?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Python's `select()` gets passed through as a `select()` system call as you are expecting, but the problem you have with it blocking is a different issue, probably relating to buffering.  Just to satify yourself that `select()` is doing the right thing, try reading/writing a file on the file system rather than using a special device such as a joystick.

You probably want to change your `open()` call.  Pythons [`open`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) call will by default use buffered reads, so even if you do a `read(8)` it will likely read more data from the input file and buffer the results.  You need to set the `buffering` option to `open` so that the joystick device is opened unbuffered.

Suggestions for you to try:

- Python defaults to opening files in text mode.  You probably want the open `mode` to be `rb` when dealing with special devices such as a joystick.
- Open file in unbuffered mode.
- Set the device into non-blocking mode if you're going to be doing `select` based calls.  Try using `os.open()` with `os.O_RDONLY|os.O_NONBLOCK` flags.

Comment: invoking `open()` with 0 buffer size do the trick, and it makes sense to me. There was no need to set the file descriptor to non-blocking neither changing the read mode. That's better, because after reading one need to `unpack()` the string into a structure.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask a stupid question - are you sure there are really 8 bytes left?

Device nodes don't necessarily behave like normal files.  It might be that you have to read the entire struct input_event in a single read() system call.  (And if you don't read enough, the rest gets thrown away).  A bit like recvmsg() on datagram sockets.

Comment: @user799204, how this is a stupid question? have you read the statements? and YES, I'm sure about that fact that was posted as an example. The only way to letting you know that is by trying yourself if you want to. The procedure to follow is to plug in a joystick, press two buttons together. That generates an event with the same time, `select()` will return. Issue `file.read(8)` and call `select()` again to see why I started this question.

Comment: Oh, and btw, 8 is the size in bytes for the specific event. But if you want to, you could use any quantity less than the total amount of bytes that are in the queue. See the accepted answer, buffering was the issue.

Comment: Apologies for my poor phrasing.  I meant my question was probably stupid.  (And it shows.  struct input_event is for "event" files only.  Your 8 bytes is the correct size for struct js_event).

Comment: It's okay with me, the edit comes fine too. Just to mention what you say about UDP packets: Are you talking about packet lost? UDP is meant to be that way, it has no control transfer. I don't imagine someone coding a driver where data 'could' be missing in a non-deterministic way. Or maybe, you are talking about a full queue issue. If your device queue is full, old events are replaced with new events, so yes, you could "lost" data that way. This was not the problem anyway. Regards.

Comment: I was wondering whether your read size was too small.  If you naively read 8 bytes from UDP, and the packet is 16 bytes, then the last 8 bytes are lost (which is reflected in a MSG_TRUNC flag).