# How to use select with Python ssl socket buffering?

Tags: python, sockets, select, ssl, buffer

My problem is similar to [python - How select.select() works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591054/python-how-select-select-works) .  However, the solution there doesn't work for me, because I'm not open()ing my file.  Instead, it's a socket.  I couldn't find any way to set it to be unbuffered in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).

I have a glib mainloop (which uses select), where I registered the socket for reading.  Because socket.recv() requires me to specify a receive buffer size, it is not unusual to read fewer bytes than the socket read.  As long as the kernel buffers them, that is fine; select will still mark the socket as "ready for reading".  But apparently Python has a buffer as well.  With large files, near the end of the data stream, recv() will read a part of it, the rest will be buffered by Python and select no longer triggers on my socket, until new data is sent.  At that point, the "missing" data is received before the new data; no data is lost.

My question is: how do I solve this?  Is there a way to disable Python's buffer on the socket?  If not, is there a way to check if the buffer is empty, so I can make sure I don't return from my callback until it is?

Edit:

As noted in the comment, Python doesn't add an extra buffer to sockets, so this could not be the problem.  I was unable to create a minimal example for the problem.  However, it seems that it may be related to using ssl sockets.  I had forgotten that I used an encrypted connection; disabling the encryption seems to solve this issue, but is not acceptable to me.  So the above question remains, with the note that the buffers are probably implemented in the ssl module.

Example code to show the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glib
import socket
import ssl

def cb (fd, cond):
    print ('data: %s' % repr (s.read (1)))
    return True

s = ssl.wrap_socket (socket.create_connection (('localhost', 1234)))
glib.io_add_watch (s.fileno (), glib.IO_IN, cb)
glib.MainLoop ().run ()
```

Then run a server with

```
openssl s_server -accept 1234 -key file.key -cert file.crt
```

Running the python program will establish the connection.  Sending more than one byte of data will make the program print only the first byte; when sending more bytes, the remaining chunks are read first, then the first new byte, then it waits again.  This is easy to understand: as long as there is data in the ssl buffer, the new byte is not read from the kernel buffer, so select continues to report it.

Comment: I'm just checked the code under [`Modules/socketmodule.c`, lines from `2485`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/socketmodule.c#l2485) where the `sock_recv` is implemented and I can assure you that python does *not* do any buffering. It creates a buffer of *exactly* the size you specify with `recv` and the calls to the system call `recv` keep track of the remaining bytes and ask for *that* many bytes, not more (see [this loop](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/socketmodule.c#l2439))

Comment: I've found that this was only happening when using ssl sockets, and added example code which shows the problem.

Comment: The solution for me was to increase the buffer size. I had `recv(4096)` in my code but the data was actually 4726 bytes. Changing it to `recv(64 * 1024)` solved the buffering vs `select()` issue.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I'd call that a workaround, not a solution. ;-)  It works if you know the size of your data in advance, but seems very fragile.  If your packet size changes later and you forget to update this, you'll have a very hard time figuring out why it doesn't work anymore.  Since the problem and solution are now known (and simple), I'd suggest using that.

Comment: @BasWijnen I wouldn't call the use of an undocumented function a final solution either. If it's a documentation (which?) / implementation bug, it should probably be reported and fixed. Also consider that a TLS record length must not be greater than `2**14` (4 kiB). Then 64 KiB is surely sufficient (assuming that the network stack does not do extra buffering). Jumbo frames also set the upper bound for Ethernet frames to about 9 kB, so that won't be an issue either.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I was talking about https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ssl.html .  I've just submitted a bug report for adding it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the ssl source, I found an undocumented function which does what I want: pending().  It can be used like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glib
import socket
import ssl

def cb(fd, cond):
    print('data: %s' % repr(s.read(1)))
    while(s.pending()):
        print('more data: %s' % repr(s.read(1)))
    return True

s = ssl.wrap_socket (socket.create_connection(('localhost', 1234)))
glib.io_add_watch(s.fileno(), glib.IO_IN, cb)
glib.MainLoop().run()
```

This solves the problem.

Comment: ... why do you put spaces between function name and arguments? Python has a well-known *official* style guide (see [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)). You should follow it *at least* when your code is supposed to be read by other people (for example, in this answer).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this style guide, so it isn't as well-known as you think (says my n=1 sample :-P)  Also, the "official" part means that it is the style that must be used when writing code _for_ Python, to be included in the official distribution.  If not, you can do whatever you like.  I agree that using a common style is a good idea, but it's not as mandatory as you make it sound.

Comment: The PEP8 has a wider scope then just the standard library. For example "The guidelines provided here are intended to improve the readability of code and make it consistent *across the wide spectrum of Python code*". the last sentence refers to all open source projects out there. In fact all the tools like `pylint` or `pychecker` used to do a bit of static analysis also include a check for PEP8 style. IDEs like PyCharm automatically show warnings when not following the PEP8. PEP8 *is the* style used when you want to show code to the python community in general.

Comment: Of course you are correct that it would be a good idea to follow it.  My defensive response was triggered by your accusation that I was ignoring the guidelines, while you should at least have considered the (IMO much more likely) option that I was simply not aware of its existence.  Simply claiming that it is well-known doesn't mean I actually know it.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I've removed the spaces; thanks for the pointer to PEP8. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-nonblocking) now have a note on this point, possibly in response to your bug report:

> Conversely, since the SSL layer has its own framing, **a SSL socket may still have data available for reading without select() being aware of it**. Therefore, you should first call SSLSocket.recv() to drain any potentially available data, and then only block on a select() call if still necessary.

If you want to avoid blocking, the solution as you note seems to be to use the `pending()` function on the `ssl.SSLSocket` class.

Edit: I tried replacing a simple call to `select` in my code with the following (`socks` is a list which may include both normal and SSL sockets). The idea is to check first if there are any pending bytes on an SSL socket before blocking on `select`:

```
r = [s for s in socks if isinstance(s, ssl.SSLSocket) and s.pending()]
if not r:
    r, _, _ = select.select(socks, [], [], 1.0)
```

It seems to work as expected. My understanding is that:

1. `select` can give false negatives for SLL sockets, but not false positives, and
2. false negatives will only occur after a previous invocation returned true and the socket was read from (i.e. because some bytes in the SSL frame remained unread)

Assuming these are both true, I think the code above should service all sockets reliably and with no unnecessary waiting or blocking.