# Python SSL - recv being offset when data larger than 1400

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, buffer

I'm using the ssl module in Python and have run in to a little problem with what seems to be buffers.

I have the following procedure to handle data from the socket, and I have also added a while loop using pending based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663705/how-to-use-select-with-python-ssl-socket-buffering) question, but it hasn't solved the problem. I have also oversized the buffer to no avail.

```
RECV_BUFFER = 131072
def handle(client_socket):
    try:
        rxdata = client_socket.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
        if rxdata:
                print("Rx: " + rxdata.decode())
                while(client_socket.pending()):
                    rxdata = client_socket.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    sys.stdout.write(rxdata.decode())
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: " + str(e))
```

For testing purposes I set up a user input so I can test directly. A `GET /` returns "Hello World" while `GET /other` returns a long string. Each time the buffer overflows the returns get offset by one, as follows.

```
Command>GET /
Tx: GET /
Rx: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: a65f614b75674fa723b7d69c1af03a0e;o=1
Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 16:00:19 GMT
Server: My Frontend
Content-Length: 12

Hello World!
Command>GET /other
Tx: GET /other
Rx: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 90033f7e308e07508106359c3e7c76d1
Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 16:00:23 GMT
Server: My Frontend
Content-Length: 1924

This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. T
Command>GET /
Tx: GET /
Rx: his is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. This is something else. End.
Command>GET /other
Tx: GET /other
Rx: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 160b0cd5f80982bf1e7ab7dd5d94996d
Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 16:00:26 GMT
Server: My Frontend
Content-Length: 12

Hello World!
```

What's going on here and how should it be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I wouldn't use both `read` and `recv` on the same SSLSocket. Also, since 3.6 `read` has been deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, problems with integrating the linked question. Recv is actually used in both instances. I'm trying to capture all output from the server, but it's getting truncated i to multiple messages.

Comment: You have this line of code in your question: `rxdata = client_socket.read(RECV_BUFFER)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution I settled on. I feel this is a more correct solution that the one previously posted. It also has options to strip the headers or leave in place by specifying `True` as the second argument:

```
def handle(client_socket, raw=False):
    data = client_socket.recv()
    reCL = re.search('Content-Length: (\d+)', data.decode(), re.MULTILINE)
    contentLength = int(reCL.group(1))
    contentLengthEndChar = reCL.end()+4
    dataSize = contentLength 
    if raw == True: dataSize += contentLengthEndChar
    sslRecordPending = math.ceil(dataSize / 16384) - 1 #SSL records left; not used
    socket_active = True
    rxdata = b''
    if raw == True: rxdata = data[:contentLengthEndChar]
    rxdata += data[contentLengthEndChar:]
    while True:
        try:
            if len(rxdata) == dataSize: break
            rxdata += client_socket.recv()
        except socket.timeout:
            break
    return rxdata.decode()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do, but I think your server works essentially like this:

1. Read the command (one line).
2. Send the full response at once.

Given that you are using `pending` which only checks if there are still decrypted data in the SSL socket my guess is that you assume that if the data is send by the server in a single `sent` then it will be read by the client at once too. But this is not the case. What actually happens here is something like this:

1. Server sends lots of day, say 20000 bytes.
2. At the SSL level these are at least two SSL records since a single record can only have a size of 16384. Thus, assume that it will do a record of 16384 and a record for the rest (3616 bytes).
3. The `ssl_socket.revc(RECV_BUFFER)` will at least read as much data from the underlying TCP connection as it needs to have a full SSL record. Then it will decrypt the SSL record and return at most `RECV_BUFFER` bytes of decrypted data.
4. `ssl_socket.pending()` will tell you if there is still unread decrypt data in the SSL socket. It will not check if there are data available at the underlying TCP socket. If there are data still in the SSL socket the next `ssl_socket.recv(...)` will return from these data but will not try to read more data from the underlying TCP socket. Only if there are no more decrypted but unread data are available in the SSL socket a `recv` will read more from the underlying TCP socket - but in this case `pending` will return false so  you will never try to read more data.

This means that it might happen that only the first SSL record is read and decrypted and returned inside your `recv`. Thus, if you send the next command you will not get the new response but you will actually read the remaining response data from the previous request.

In order to fix the code you need to fix your assumption: SSL need to be treated like a data stream and not like a message protocol (same for TCP). This means you cannot assume that the message gets read in full and that it will be returned in full or that it is least already in full in the SSL object. Instead you either need to know the size of the response up-front (like prefixing the response with a length) or need to have some clear marker that the response has ended and read until this marker.

Comment: How would I implement a marker to know that the response has ended?

Comment: @fileinster: such a marker could be simply the end of all data, i.e. close of connection (which of course then need to be opened again). Or some character or sequence which does not occur otherwise in the data or is escaped in the rest of the data (for example use within SMTP DATA command - a line with only a "." marks the end of the mail). But knowing the length up-front is usually the simpler option, for example use by HTTP with the `Content-length` header.

Comment: Right... so what you are saying is there is no innate way to know if there are records left to be read without trying it?

Comment: @fileinster: You might try a combination of `pending` (check if there are still already decrypted data) and `select` (check if more data could be read from the underlying TCP socket). But, this is a dirty hack and also assumes that all packets have already been arrived - which will probably happen most times but sometimes the rest will take longer due to traffic congestion or similar problems.

Comment: I was not aware of select, and that was the answer. Thank you! I'll post my working code for posterity.

Comment: @fileinster: `select` is very challenging to get working with SSL. Unless you are an SSL expert I wouldn't touch it. Plus, it doesn't solve your problem at all.